# I Would Like To Host an HTML Website Without Using Server.app

Tags: macos, apache, html, hosts

I am somewhat a novice when it comes to the Apache web server. I currently host Ruby on Rails applications on my Mac Mini Server (Mavericks) using Phusion Passenger.  I know that some of the config files are in different libraries than the standard Apache implementation.  I'm currently using Server.app to host one HTML website.  I would like to stop using Server.app to host it but I do not know how to set this up in Apache on an Apple machine.  The solutions I have found are not specific to the Apple setup for Apache.

I would appreciate help on how to do this from anyone who has done this.

Comment: Is this for a public or private website?

Comment: A public website using a GoDaddy domain.

Comment: I already have the domain set up to point to my server.  I know how to create the virtual host entries for Phusion Passenger entries for my Ruby on Rails applications.  My guess is that I need to go to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf as mentioned by @sdmeyers below instead of the server app configuration file.  I just need help on how to create the virtual host entry for the html website in /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.

Comment: I'm just wondering what has you wanting to quit using Server? Deploying your website(s) on Server is going to be far easier than learning Apache configuration parameters. But if you want to drop Server and use the built-in Apache server, I'm sure there is plenty of info available through some Google searching.

Comment: I want to stop using Server.app because I'm using the PostgreSQL database for my Ruby on Rails applications.  Using the built-in PostgreSQL requires that I use the Server.app which turns on the database.  I have had database problems with corrupting or destroying my databases with server.app upgrades. Other solutions require that only one active PostgreSQL data can exist.  I asked this question because I could not find complete examples for hosting html websites in Apache.  I will look again.  I'm sure the parameters are not much different than what I use to host my RoR apps Phusion Passenger.

Comment: Okay, I'd still suggest some Google searching to guide you through getting Apache configured as you want under OS X. As @sdmeyers noted, there are some specific OS X modules added to Apache you'll need to be mindful of, but overall it's a standard Apache instance and the Apache documentation should be a good starting reference for getting it set up.

Comment: I was able to get my website hosted through Apache after searching.  I turned off the Websites service in the Server App.  I still use the Server App for DNS maintenance.  I was able to implement postgres.app successfully with a few modifications to my Ruby on Rails applications.  There appears to be no conflict at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Apache is there by default, you just need to turn it on:

`sudo apachectl start`

To tweak it to do what you want you may need to adjust the .conf files located at `/etc/apache2/` These behave like any other apache configuration (though there are a few OS X specific modules installed).